# The data for bipartite graph (in R) can only be 0 and 1?

Tags: r, heatmap, bipartite

I would like to create bipartite graph and heatmap for my data 
of two symbiotic partners.
I have installed the needed package but unable to generate the graph.
Is it because that my data can only be consisted of 1 and 0 ?
.
I saw a video online and his data is just 0 and 1.
I tried but couldn't find other examples. someone please help clarify this?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Wanji. You will increase your chances of an answer if you try to follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) guidelines.

Comment: Short answer: for `bipartite` R package, data can be both presence-absence (0-1) and also abundance (counts)